# Is there an analytical solution for cumulative probability for a distribution generated via a set of parameters? (mean, variance, skew, kurtosis)

Tags: probability, distributions, maximum-likelihood, cumulative-distribution-function, moments

I am trying to build a model that creates probabilistic estimates of the next location of an event, given a series of previous events (and other data).

I want to maximize the likelihood that the next event occurs in some correct location $L$. The problem (as I understand it) can be expressed as:
$$
\mathcal{L}(Location_{t+1} = L | X_{0:t}) = \Pr(X_{0:t} | location_{t+1} = L) = 1 - \Pr(X_{0:t} | location_{t+1} < L) - \Pr(X_{0:t} | location_{t+1} > L)
$$

If I was to generate the probability distribution using mean, variance, skew, and kurtosis as parameters, how would I calculate the cumulative density of the generated distribution?

**Edit:**

The idea was to use this approach: ragulpr.github.io/2016/12/22/WTTE-RNN-Hackless-churn-modeling/, but instead of a weibull, use a normal distribution (parameterized by mean, variance, skew, kurtosis) so that instead of point estimates for location, I have a distribution about each latitude/longitude value. Unfortunately in this case,

Comment: I think you are conflating parameter estimation with forecasting/prediction. The likelihood is a function of the parameter vector $\theta$, given the data $x$. If your random variable is indeed the location $L$, whose realizations are your data, then, after having defined a suitable probabilistic model including $\theta$, you would proceed to find the values of $\theta$ that maximize $\mathcal{L}(\theta\mid x)$. What you're after sounds (to me) more like a Markov chain of some order $m$.

Comment: The idea was to use this approach: https://ragulpr.github.io/2016/12/22/WTTE-RNN-Hackless-churn-modeling/#churn-prediction-is-hard
, but instead of a weibull, use a normal distribution (parameterized by mean, variance, skew, kurtosis) so that instead of point estimates for location, I have a distribution about each latitude/longitude value. Unfortunately in this case, I don't know what I don't know..

Comment: I have voted to close this question. The specific question is unclear including: (1) a strange interpretation/use of the term likelihood, (2) the presented equation is unclear, (3) the principle is too broad *"to generate the probability distribution using mean, variance, skew, and kurtosis as parameters"* (for instance 'what probability distribution?' these parameters do not define a unique probability distribution).

Comment: (4) There is a link to a long story on some other website which is supposed to relate to the approach but there is no explanation how this is related and what a bystander, trying to answer the question, is supposed to look for.

Comment: Likelihood is not a synonym for conditional probability. If you have a normal distribution, then its skewness and kurtosis are defined automatically. Conversely, knowing mean, variance, skewness and kurtosis is not in general enough information to tie down a distribution.

Comment: My apologies, I didn't know what likelihood actually meant. What I wanted was what ragulpr has suggested, a model that predicts distribution parameters for the location of an event.

As for the distribution, what I wanted was a discrete skew-normal distribution, which I can't seem to find on google scholar or anywhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you like the WTTE-approach for Time-To-Event data it's even easier for this problem and been done for ages. Just train a Gaussian Mixed Density Network (MDN), with target at every timestep being the coordinate. You would then predict $\mu$ and $\sigma$ which controls the shape of a predicted Normal distribution (heatmap/density) of where the next location is in each step. You could use this for probabilistic queries. I would look into Edward (tensorflow), Pyro (pytorch) or just plain Pytorch. Just Google for MDNs.

If you have *censored data* the same principles of WTTE applies, but you will have to derive the right- left- or interval- censored log-likelihood loss yourself because I haven't had a reason to work with non-positive data yet.

Edit: I read question as "~I have sequences of location data and want to predict something like a probability distribution over the next location". It follows from link provided.

Comment: "ages" seems a little exaggerated here: could you add precise references?

Comment: MDNs typically attributed Bishop (1994) but the idea of predicting other parameters than the location parameters (as is done in regression) must be much older and probably shouldn't be attributed to Bishop and especially not me.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you.